# rsyslog mysql change format

Tags: linux, rsyslog

I have rsyslog 7.6.7 on server with some file who contains

```
2018-07-19 12:38:49~,~"Phone" <672094>~,~672094~,~0~,~atx_78342~,~SIP/teleserver-1.ha-000000ce~,~SIP/s_ru-000000cf~,~Dial~,~SIP/s_ru/1#00#100,,trg~,~4.880648~,~0.000000~,~NO ANSWER~,~DOCUMENTATION~,~~,~~,~212.62.62.11~,~6282837472.210~,~~,~in_sajdh3hg2321nb312bv3sae3b2j4v2k3jgv42h3gv423~,~~,~2018-07-19 12:38:53
2018-07-19 12:38:49~,~"Phone" <672094>~,~672094~,~100~,~atx_78342~,~SIP/s_en-000000d0~,~SIP/s_ru-000000d1~,~Dial~,~SIP/s_ru/59393-100,20,t~,~4.551456~,~0.000000~,~NO ANSWER~,~DOCUMENTATION~,~~,~~,~~,~6282837472.212~,~~,~in_sajdh3hg2321nb312bv3sae3b2j4v2k3jgv42h3gv423~,~~,~2018-07-19 12:38:53
2018-07-19 12:39:21~,~"Phone" <672094>~,~672094~,~59393-100~,~search_peer_context~,~SIP/s_en-000000d7~,~SIP/teleserver-dev.ha-000000e4~,~Hangup~,~31~,~18.012724~,~0.000000~,~NO ANSWER~,~DOCUMENTATION~,~~,~~,~~,~1984726432.219~,~~,~in_sajdh3hg2321nb312bv3sae3b2j4v2k3jgv42h3gv423~,~~,~2018-07-19 12:39:39
```

I need to get it from this file and put into mysql with rsyslog to table

```
CREATE TABLE atx_asterisk_cdr (
  calldate datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  clid varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  src varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  dst varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  dcontext varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  channel varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  dstchannel varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  lastapp varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  lastdata varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  duration int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  billsec int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  disposition varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  amaflags int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  accountcode varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  userfield varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  userip varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  uniqueid varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  called_did varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  atx_call_id varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY calldate (calldate),
  KEY dst (dst),
  KEY accountcode (accountcode),
  KEY clid (clid),
  KEY src (src),
  KEY dcontext (dcontext),
  KEY channel (channel),
  KEY dstchannel (dstchannel),
  KEY lastdata (lastdata),
  KEY duration (duration),
  KEY billsec (billsec),
  KEY disposition (disposition),
  KEY amaflags (amaflags),
  KEY userfield (userfield),
  KEY uniqueid (uniqueid),
  KEY called_did (called_did),
  KEY atx_call_id (atx_call_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I use for it imfile and ommysql . So, could you please help me make template to change format this messages for my mysql table?